# How to change the property of each mapped value so that my component can be used more dynamically for each event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, foreach, mapping

Sorry I am new and still understanding mapping and for loops so I'm not sure if I'm even asking this question correctly. How can I make my map function more dynamic so that I don't have to hard code each  to change the property of [1], [2], [3] etc. I want it to just do all of them until there aren't anymore.

```
    const handleInputSearch = (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        let result = [];
        if (value.length === 4) {
            setFilteredData(allData.filter((data) => {
                return data.year === value;
            }));
            result = allData.filter((data) => {
                return data.year === value;
            });
            console.log('filteredData', filteredData)
        }
    }


{filteredData.map((value, index) => {
   return (
      <div style={{
         height: `600px`,
         overflow: "scroll"
      }}>
         <Event
            category={value.children[0][1].category}
            title={value.children[0][1].title}
            subtitle={value.children[0][1].subtitle}
            body={value.children[0][1].body}
            image={value.children[0][1].image}
         >
         </Event>
         <Event
            category={value.children[0][2].category}
            title={value.children[0][2].title}
            subtitle={value.children[0][2].subtitle}
            body={value.children[0][2].body}
            image={value.children[0][2].image}
         >
         </Event>
         <Event
            category={value.children[0][3].category}
            title={value.children[0][3].title}
            subtitle={value.children[0][3].subtitle}
            body={value.children[0][3].body}
            image={value.children[0][3].image}
         >
         </Event>
         <Event
            category={value.children[0][4].category}
            title={value.children[0][4].title}
            subtitle={value.children[0][4].subtitle}
            body={value.children[0][4].body}
            image={value.children[0][4].image}
         >
         </Event>
      </div>
)})}
```

and here is what my filtered data is returning:

```
filteredData 
[{…}]
0:
children: Array(1)
0:
1: {title: "High Times", subtitle: "On Meeting Thomas King Forcade", category: "Marijuana", body: "Thomas King Forçade created High Times magazine. T…g, with head shops opening up around the country.", image: "thomaskingforcade.jpeg", …}
2: {title: "Oakland Athletics", subtitle: "Win the World Series", category: "Culture", body: "The Oakland A's sweep the World Series against the…as an easy win because the Nats didn't exist yet.", image: "oaklandathletics.jpeg", …}
3: {title: "President Nixon Announces Bombing in Cambodia", subtitle: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet", category: "National", body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…aliquet. Fusce varius mattis nisl, in lacinia mi.", image: "nixoncambodia.jpeg", …}
4: {title: "NYPD Foils the French Connection", subtitle: "Real-life bust was the basis for the Oscar-winning film", category: "Opioids", body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…aliquet. Fusce varius mattis nisl, in lacinia mi.", image: "frenchconnection.jpeg", …}
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
year: "1974"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Please provide the `filteredData` array. Are you currently getting the output you want?

Comment: I added some more information, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You Could Try Something like this
You could try replacing the hardcoded values with the index

```
  {filteredData.map((value, index) => {
   return (
      <div style={{
         height: `600px`,
         overflow: "scroll"
      }}>
         <Event
            category={value.children[index][++index].category}
            title={value.children[index][++index].title}
            subtitle={value.children[index][++index].subtitle}
            body={value.children[index][++index].body}
            image={value.children[index][++index].image}
         >
         </Event>
         <Event
            category={value.children[index][index+=2].category}
            title={value.children[index][index+=2].title}
            subtitle={value.children[index][index+=2].subtitle}
            body={value.children[index][index+=2].body}
            image={value.children[index][index+=2].image}
         >
         </Event>
         <Event
            category={value.children[index][index+=3].category}
            title={value.children[index][index+=3].title}
            subtitle={value.children[index][index+=3].subtitle}
            body={value.children[index][index+=3].body}
            image={value.children[index][index+=3].image}
         >
         </Event>
         <Event
            category={value.children[index][index+=4].category}
            title={value.children[index][index+=4].title}
            subtitle={value.children[index][index+=4].subtitle}
            body={value.children[index][index+=4].body}
            image={value.children[index][index+=4].image}
         >
         </Event>
      </div>
)})}
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your `filteredData.children` could likely be improved. If you might have more than one index in the `children` array then maybe it's fine, although it seems like the content of elements in the `children` array should be arrays as well and not an object. But we can work around that using `Object.values`.

Here I will assume that your `filteredData` and `children` arrays might have more than a single element. I'm also assuming that you want to wrap each `filteredData` in that div, if you wanted to wrap the div around each `children` element you'd have to move the div inside the `children.map` loop. So I would do something like this:

```
//Map each index in filteredData
filteredData.map(dataItem => {
    return (
        <div
         style={{height: `600px`, overflow: "scroll"}}
        >
            {/* map each index in the children array */}
            {dataItem.children.map((child, childIndex) => {
                //Converting the object in each index of children into an array and immediately mapping over that array 
                //read docs for Object.values, Object.keys and Object.entries for more info on this.
                Object.values(child[childIndex]).map(eventItem => {
                    return (
                        <Event
                            category={eventItem.category}
                            title={eventItem.title}
                            subtitle={eventItem.subtitle}
                            body={eventItem.body}
                            image={eventItem.image}
                        />
                    )
                })
            })
            }
        </div>
    )
})
```

I haven't run this code but it should work, might need minor adjustments. With this style of looping everything you can now expand your `filteredData` as much as you like, each item's `children` and each index of all those `children` arrays will be rendered as `Event` components.